# Typeerror: failed to execute `removeChild` on `node`: parameter 1 is not a type of `node`

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

this is a delete function for a primarykey and it should allow me to delete the key in database aswell as the tablerow in txtTabell.innerHTML for the same pk, this code use to work but suddenly stopped working.
Thanks for help!

```
function slett(pk) {
    var sletttime = arrangement.child(pk);
    sletttime.remove();
    var tr = document.getElementById(`${pk}`);
    txtTabell.removeChild(tr);

}
```

This is another delete function for another element in txtTabell2.innerHTML.

```
function fjern(pkk) {
    var slettruss = russ.child(pkk);
    slettruss.remove();
}
```

These functions bring up the content of the innerHTMLs

```
    function hentArrangement(snapshot){
    var pk = snapshot.key;
    var nyTime = snapshot.val();
    var russRef = database.ref("russ/" + nyTime.russ);
    russRef.on("value", function(snapshotruss){
        var pkk = snapshotruss.key;
        var russObj = snapshotruss.val();
        txtTabell.innerHTML += `
        <tr id="${pk}">
        <td><label class="russlabel" onclick="edit('${pk}')">${nyTime.arrangør}</label><input type="text" class="editItem" style="display:none"></td>
        <td>${nyTime.adresse}</td>
        <td>${nyTime.postadresse}</td>
        <td>${nyTime.poststed}</td>
        <td>${nyTime.pris}</td>
        <td>${russObj.navn}</td>
        <td>${russObj.russadresse}</td>
        <td>${russObj.mobilnr}</td>
        <td>${russObj.kjonn}</td>
        </tr>`;

        txtTabell2.innerHTML +=`
        <tr =${pkk}>
            <td>${russObj.navn}</td>
            <td>${russObj.russadresse}</td>
            <td>${russObj.mobilnr}</td>
            <td>${russObj.kjonn}</td>
            <td><label class="delete" onclick="slett('${pk},${pkk}')"><button>Slett</button></label></td>
        </tr>`;


    });
} 

function hentRuss(snapshot){
    var russNoekkel = snapshot.key;
    var russInfo = snapshot.val();

    inpRuss.innerHTML += `<option value="${russNoekkel}">${russInfo.navn}</option>`;

};
```

Comment: Are you sure getElementById is returning a node?

Comment: **_this code use to work but suddenly stopped working._** -- what changed?

Comment: so my first table used to show 2 different data in one table, i tried to make another table allowing it to see 2 different data in one table and by clicking a button one of the data sets would appear in another table.

Comment: according to my log tr=null, but i dont get what the problem is because the tr is created and works properly the only problem is that it wont delete

Comment: i removed the ('${pk},${pkk}') and wrote ('${pk}') and by doing this i can delete the first element, but the other element is still there, how do i delete both?

Answer (score 0):

i found it out guys, i wrote the delete function like this:

```
function slett(pk,pkk) {
    var slettruss = russ.child(pkk)
    var tr = document.getElementById(`${pkk}`)
    txtTabell2.removeChild(tr);

    var sletttime = arrangement.child(pk);
    sletttime.remove();
    var tr = document.getElementById(`${pk}`);
    txtTabell.removeChild(tr);

}
```

and i the delete button looks like this:
            txtTabell.innerHTML += 
            `<tr id="${pk}">
            <td><label class="russlabel" onclick="edit('${pk}')">${nyTime.arrangør}</label><input type="text" class="editItem" style="display:none"></td>
            <td>${nyTime.adresse}</td>
            <td>${nyTime.postadresse}</td>
            <td>${nyTime.poststed}</td>
            <td>${nyTime.pris}</td>
            <td>${russObj.navn}</td>
            <td>${russObj.russadresse}</td>
            <td>${russObj.mobilnr}</td>
            <td>${russObj.kjonn}</td>
            </tr>`;

```
        txtTabell2.innerHTML +=`
        <tr id=${pkk}>
            <td>${russObj.navn}</td>
            <td>${russObj.russadresse}</td>
            <td>${russObj.mobilnr}</td>
            <td>${russObj.kjonn}</td>
            <td><label class="delete" onclick="slett**('${pk}','${pkk}')**"><button>Slett</button></label></td>
        </tr>`;
```

the problem was the delete button and how i wrote them.